# Selecting a dropdown textbox error produced was Element should have been "select" but was "span"

Tags: selenium

Want to select a value in dropdown textbox , which is the all value , what happens is it produces an error , element was not select but div/span

Tried select dropdown

```
<div id="ddllocation_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 398px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1"><span>ALL 全部</span><div><b></b></div></a>
<div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 396.008px; top: 24px;">
    <div class="chzn-search">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 361.016px;">
    </div>
    <ul class="chzn-results">
        <li id="ddllocation_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style=""><em>A</em>LL 全部</li>
        <li id="ddllocation_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">Quirino Br<em>a</em>nch Main</li>
        <li id="ddllocation_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">Br<em>a</em>nch 1</li>
        <li id="ddllocation_chzn_o_3" class="active-result" style="">Br<em>a</em>nch 2</li>
        <li id="ddllocation_chzn_o_4" class="active-result" style="">Br<em>a</em>nch 3</li>
        <li id="ddllocation_chzn_o_5" class="active-result" style="">Br<em>a</em>nch 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Quirino Branch Main')]")).click();
    WebElement location = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Quirino Branch Main')]"));
    location.click();   

    WebElement Dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Quirino Branch Main')]"));
    Select SelectDropdown= new Select(Dropdown);
    SelectDropdown.selectByVisibleText("ALL 全部");
```

I expect to click the all value

Answer (score 0):

That drop down is made of **ul** and **li** tags so `Select class` from **Selenium** will not work. `Select class` from **selenium** is meant for `select tag` in **HTML**.

Since it is made of **ul** and **li**, you have to store elements in a list and try to get web elements and then you can try to click on it.

**Steps :**

1. Click on the drop down. 
   You have to write the code for that since no HTML is provided.
2. Get all drop down elements in a list.

You can try `li[id^='ddllocation_chzn']` locator to get all elements in a list like this :

```
  drop_down = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li[id^='ddllocation_chzn']')  
    for drop in drop_down: 
        if drop.text == 'Branch 2':
           drop.click()
```

Comment: invalid character constant

Comment: in which line ?

Comment: drop_down = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('ddllocation_chzn']')

Comment: Well, I have written `drop_down = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li[id^='ddllocation_chzn']')`

Comment: try with this `drop_down = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li[id^='ddllocation_chzn']")`